# Rails 4: User can only view their own orders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, permissions

I am giving clients the ability to place food orders through my app.  They can view their order index by visiting the following URL:

```
localhost:3000/clients/[:client_id]/food_orders
```

... and I've limited the index to only show orders belonging to that user:

```
@food_orders = @client.food_orders
```

...but if they were to visit `localhost:3000/clients/[:client_id]/food_orders/5` and food order #5 was not their order, they can still view it.

**How are you supposed to limit the users so they can only access their own orders?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should chain your finds like this, then the user can only see his/her own orders.

```
def show
  @food_order = @client.food_orders.find_by(id: params[:id])

  redirect_to root_path if @food_order.nil?
end
```

Comment: Ahhh.. so obvious.  For some reason it didn't occur to me.  Thanks!